# What is this "4 white bubbles with a red dot" notification icon?

Tags: notifications

I see this in my notification bar, but I have no idea what it is

[image]

Scrolling down my notification bar doesn't show what it is, and my notification log doesn't show it either.

What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Google Assistant. See [this](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/P1-P1m-P70-P90-Series/white-circle-with-red-point-on-notification/td-p/3695270)